# React, useRef not allowing to access current properties, getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientHeight')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm storing a reference to an image item using: `const renderedImageRef = useRef()`. The ref is then assigned in `render()` function using:

```
<img ref={renderedImageRef} src=... />
```

In another JSX item below, I try to access `renderedImageRef.current.clientHeight` using:

```
<div style={{top:`${renderedImageRef.current.clientHeight}px`}}>
   Hello world
</div>
```

But this produces an error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'clientHeight')
```

Strangely enough, if I try to access `renderedImageRef.current.clientHeight` from inside a `useEffect` hook, it displays the height correctly:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(renderedImageRef !== null) {
        console.log(renderedImageRef)
    }
}, [renderedImageRef])
```

Why am I getting the console error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible answer is that this line:

```
<div style={{top:`${renderedImageRef.current.clientHeight}px`}}>Hello world</div>
```

is coming in your code before this one:

```
<img ref={renderedImageRef} src=... />
```

In which case, it is normal that you are getting the error. It is to know that when you call `const renderedImageRef = useRef()`, the value of `renderedImageRef` is `{current:undefined}`. The JSX must be rendered before a `ref` gets its value in the `current` field.

A solution is to use a state for the `top`:

```js
const [top, setTop] = useState(0);
useEffect(() => {
  // At this point, the current is defined. This if is useful in case you use TypeScript
  if (renderedImageRef.current) {
    setTop(renderedImageRef.current.clientHeight);
  }
}, []);
```

```
<div style={{top:`${top}px`}}>Hello world</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Next.JS, I think you have to change the dependency to renderedImageRef.current. So something like this:

```
const [top, setTop]=useState(0)
useEffect(() => {
    if(renderedImageRef.current) {
        setTop(renderedImageRef.current.clientHeight);
    }
}, [renderedImageRef.current])
```